# How to get broadcast object from SparkContext using its id?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to get a broadcasted variable using its `id` instead of passing it around as an argument to functions?

Comment: Well, you can always make it a global variable and access it using broadcastvar.value wherever you like. That's how I handle it, as it is effectively a global static and immutable variable.

Comment: @ChrisChambers You should make it an answer.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

you can't.

yet, you can write a wrapper that will hold a broadcast map with key and value, 
key will be your id, and value will be pointer to broadcast.